# I installed rstudio and I'm having the indicated problem

Tags: r, installation, rstudio

I installed rstudio and when I start rstudio, I'm having this problem.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you need to install R as well? https://www.r-project.org/

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't install `R`. If so, then move to [here](https://cran.r-project.org/) to download the version you like and install

---

If you have installed `R` but RStudio cannot find the path, then you can manually set the path via `Tools --> Global Options --> General` in RStudio

[image]